# rstrip() the unwanted parts from string column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of strings consists of the following values:

`'20/25+1'`
`'9/200E'`
`'20/50+1'`
`'20/30 @ 8 inches'`
`'20/60-2+1'`
`'20/20 !!'`
`'20/20(slow)'`
`'20/70-1 "slowly"'`

And I only want the first fraction, so I am trying to find a way to get to the following values:

`'20/25'`
`'9/200'`
`'20/50'`
`'20/30'`
`'20/60'`
`'20/20'`
`'20/20'`
`'20/70'`

I have tried the following command but it doesn't seem to do the job:

```
df['colname'].apply(lambda x: x.rstrip(' .*')).unique()
```

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason your code doesn't work is that your code will strip the literal string " .*", and that's not present in your text.   The regex solution below is the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the fraction would always start the column's value, we can use `str.extract` here as follows:

```py
df['pct'] = df['colname'].str.extract(r'^(\d+/\d+)')
```

### Demo